# How more than 2 parallel api requests can change database without skipping one or more of them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, database, postgresql

I have an endpoint uploads images and updates a database table.

I send 3 requests to this endpoint at same time. Actually this problem happens when I send more than 2 API requests.

1. First request that comes to endpoint uploads images and updates database table successfully.
2. Second request that comes to endpoint uploads images sees database changes of first request, and updates database table successfully.
3. Third request that comes to endpoint uploads images, doesn't see database changes of second request, and updates database table successfully.
4. As a result; only database changes of first request and third request apply. Database changes of second request is not able to applied successfully or is overridden, somehow.

I use **pg** npm package.

Is problem in my code or in **pg** package.

How can this problem be solved?

Controller:

```
@UseStaffPermissionsGuards('upsert', 'VehicleCondition')
@ApiBody({ type: VehiclePhotoConditionInfoImageDTO })
@ApiResponse({ status: 201 })
@Post(':id/photos/:photoConditionId/image')
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('images'), FilesToBodyInterceptor)
async upsertImages(
  @Param('id') vehicleId: string,
  @Param('photoConditionId') photoConditionId: string,
  @Body() vehiclePhotoConditionInfoImages: VehiclePhotoConditionInfoImageDTO,
): Promise<void> {
  return this.vehiclePhotoConditionService.upsertImages(
    vehicleId,
    photoConditionId,
    vehiclePhotoConditionInfoImages,
  );
}
```

Service:

```
async upsertImages(
    vehicleId: string,
    vehiclePhotoConditionId: string,
    vehiclePhotoConditionImage: VehiclePhotoConditionInfoImageDTO,
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.isVehicleExist(vehicleId);

    const vehiclePhotoCondition = await this.getOne(vehicleId, vehiclePhotoConditionId);

    if (!vehiclePhotoCondition) {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        `The vehicle photo condition ${vehiclePhotoConditionId} is not found`,
      );
    }

    const imageKeys = await this.handleImages(vehiclePhotoConditionId, vehiclePhotoConditionImage);

    const updatedVehiclePhotoConditions = vehiclePhotoCondition.info.map((data) => {
      if (data.vehiclePart === vehiclePhotoConditionImage.vehiclePart) {
        data.uploadedImagesKeys.push(...imageKeys);
      }

      return data;
    });

    const query = sql
      .update('vehicle_photo_condition', {
        info: JSON.stringify(updatedVehiclePhotoConditions),
        updated_at: sql('now()'),
      })
      .where({ id: vehiclePhotoConditionId });

    await this.db.query(query.toParams());
  }
```

Comment: Please post code as text, NOT as images for a whole variety of reasons, not the least of which is if I wanted to offer you a code fix in an answer, I'd have to retype all that code from the image, because I can't copy/paste it..  It also can't be searched, is hard to read on mobile, etc...

Comment: Added it as text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I am posting correct code.

Here is the explanation:

In previous code, I was updating inner jsonb array of objects in code and because of the fact that the below code took some time and asynchronicity of the NodeJS, previous request can take more time than the other requests that will come later and this situation can cause data inconsistency.

Here is the previous code:

```
const updatedVehiclePhotoConditions = vehiclePhotoCondition.info.map((data) => {
      if (data.vehiclePart === vehiclePhotoConditionImage.vehiclePart) {
        data.uploadedImagesKeys.push(...imageKeys);
      }

      return data;
    });
```

In current code, I am updating inner jsonb array of object in database and let database do this operation. So, no data consistency happened.

Here is current code:

```
const query = {
  text: `
    UPDATE vehicle_photo_condition
    SET info = s.json_array
    FROM (
      SELECT
        jsonb_agg(
          CASE WHEN obj ->> 'vehiclePart' = $1 THEN
            jsonb_set(obj, '{uploadedImagesKeys}', $2)
          ELSE obj END
        ) as json_array
      FROM vehicle_photo_condition, jsonb_array_elements(info) obj WHERE id = $3
    ) s WHERE id = $3`,
  values: [
    vehiclePhotoConditionImage.vehiclePart,
    JSON.stringify(imageKeys),
    vehiclePhotoConditionId,
  ],
};

async upsertImages(
    vehicleId: string,
    vehiclePhotoConditionId: string,
    vehiclePhotoConditionImage: VehiclePhotoConditionInfoImageDTO,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const vehiclePhotoCondition = await this.getOne(vehicleId, vehiclePhotoConditionId);

    if (!vehiclePhotoCondition) {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        `The vehicle photo condition ${vehiclePhotoConditionId} is not found`,
      );
    }

    const imageKeys = await this.handleImages(vehiclePhotoConditionId, vehiclePhotoConditionImage);

    const query = {
      text: `
        UPDATE vehicle_photo_condition
        SET info = s.json_array
        FROM (
          SELECT
            jsonb_agg(
              CASE WHEN obj ->> 'vehiclePart' = $1 THEN
                jsonb_set(obj, '{uploadedImagesKeys}', $2)
              ELSE obj END
            ) as json_array
          FROM vehicle_photo_condition, jsonb_array_elements(info) obj WHERE id = $3
        ) s WHERE id = $3`,
      values: [
        vehiclePhotoConditionImage.vehiclePart,
        JSON.stringify(imageKeys),
        vehiclePhotoConditionId,
      ],
    };

    await this.db.query(query);
  }
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful to others if you can add some words that explain what technique you used to solve the problem.  I know the code is there, but explanation is useful also.  As it stands now, we have to do a manual visual diff to try to figure out what you changed and why.